# Bootstrap 4 input checkbox toggle collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying, when using bootstrap 4, to create a button where you when clicking on it will collapse into a form. The problem I have met is that you cannot write 'data-toggle="collapse"' because it will override the 'Bootstrap Toggle' CSS, into an simple checkbox. I know when using 'button' it is possible to make collapse but I want the animation from 'Bootstrap Toggle', there is a problem as it uses 'inpu't and not 'button'. I need you help with a solution that when toggling from yes to no then it collapses into an form with multiple checkboxes that override the cell of the table. Thanks in advance!!

Created example, run the code!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <style>

  </style>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Toggle Switch Animation -->
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="background: white">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              <p class="pt-2">Example 1 </p>
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
              <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-toggle="dropdown-menu" data-size="small" data-on="yes" data-off="no" data-offstyle="danger">
    </div>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <p class="pt-2">Example 2 </p>
      </th>
      <th scope="row">
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="yes" data-off="no" data-offstyle="danger">
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <p class="pt-2">Example 3 </p>
      </th>
      <th scope="row">
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="yes" data-off="no" data-offstyle="danger">
      </th>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>


  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```